# Compiler error is coming as 'request for member 'price' in something not a structure or union'

Tags: c

I am just trying to learn C and trying to understand the structs and the pointers. One of the programs I wrote is getting compiler error as below:

> :29:18: error: request for member 'price' in something not a structure or union.

Sample program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  {
    char *Title;
    float price;
} Book;


int main()
{
    int a  = 10;
    Book *HFJ = malloc(sizeof *HFJ)  ;
    HFJ->Title = "Head First Java";
    HFJ->price = 200;
    void *object;
    object = &a;
    printf("Value of object is %d", * (int*)object);
    printf("Value of HFJ %f", HFJ->price);
    object = HFJ;
    (Book*)object->price = 300;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website to your bookmarks, and look quite often into it; both for the C language, and for the functions of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (e.g. `malloc`; `printf` etc...). Later, refer also to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) when in doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *guess* the line you're getting the error on is this one

```
(Book*)object->price = 300;
```

The error is because of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), where the "arrow" operator `->` have higher precedence than the cast operator.

That means your statement is really like this:

```
(Book*)(object->price) = 300;
```

That means you're try to dereference the `void *` variable `object` (which is not really possible) and then cast the `price` member to `Book *`.

To correct it use

```
((Book*)object)->price = 300;
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) :) That solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
(Book*)object->price = 300;
```

is equivalent to

```
((Book*)(object->price)) = 300;
```

You want

```
((Book*)object)->price = 300;
```